# iPhone Application - How to create a login page that requires twitter user accounts?

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter

I am creating an iPhone application ..this is how my application works,

1)Upon opening the application,the user will be prompted to login.The users are required to login using their twitter account.

2)After login,they will see my comment page...upon commenting..it will appear on both facebook and twitter..

How do i go about doing this?I am not sure how to integrate my login page with twitter.I am totally new to coding/progamming.

Please help me out.thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is checkout both Twitter and Facebook's API's(Application Programming Interface). They will give you everything you need, including documentation, to make successful logins and updates to the users account, however I don't believe your current model will work as explained. I'm not 100% certain but I'm pretty sure that for both API's, at app start up, the user must login before making any updates, meaning your users will have to login to both services each time they launch your app. It may be a little simpler now that Twitter is built into iOS but like I said I'm not 100% sure on that. Good luck with your app man! Let me know if you need any extra help.

Comment: Thanks alot man.I will check it out.I will post any queries if i have any.Appreciate it

Comment: Sorry man, can i check with you where can i get a sample twitter application code for xcode? I kind of running out of time to build a new twitter application out. but just i basically need to link my twitter account into the twitter application? Guidance pls

Comment: Sure man, [This should be exactly what you're looking for](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5519/beginning-twitter-in-ios-5). His site is a great source of tutorials, I highly recommend this. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks man!! i will see how i can go about it fixing my situation with your solution given. In the mean time if you have anything else that could help do post here ya :D really really appreciate the help you given.

Comment: Urgent Question here!! i would like to link my facbook page RSS feed into my application. But it keep prompting that my URL is no longer valid and ask me for a new URL but there is no where to be found.. How can i go around getting this done??